# Commit Each Change from Eclipse to GitHub as a different Branch

Tags: java, eclipse, github

Anyone know how to commit each change made in Eclipse to GitHub as a different branch, then at the end of coding, merging the branches?

I'm fairly new to using Eclipse and GitHub and have an assignment to utilise both and not quite sure if I'm doing the correct thing.

I've downloaded the desktop version of GitHub and right clicked on my last commit and selected "create branch from commit" but in doing this, my changes are in the main and the new branch...

Is that always going to happen with each commit, that it's in the new branch and in main? Or will each change commited into GitHub update all branches?

TIA :)

Comment: First create the branch, then commit. Also make sure you are on the branch you want to merge to (e.g. main) before creating the new branch.